# How to enable HTTP/2 on Windows 10

Tags: http2

I have done some reading and I am following this:

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#iis-with-http2-demo-walkthrough)

After creating the certificate I am running my web application but the console still shows http/1.1. Not sure what else I am missing. Any idea what that might be?

Thanks

Comment: So you want HTTP2 in IIS? What kind of application are you hosting?

Comment: That is Angular based web app with .Net backend written in c#. But according to the MS doc everything should be using HTTP/2.

Comment: Are you using https? It won't work without https.

Comment: Yes, I have created a certificate as it is described in the doc. I am using https although Browser says it's not secure. However, the app is running.

Comment: I just noticed that Windows authentication (NTLM/Kerberos/Negotiate) is not supported with HTTP/2. My app does use Windows Authentication. Is that the reason?